# req.body option selected express ejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

Hi would like to send the selected option in dropdown menu, to show only the products from my mongodb.
If i use a submit button, works, but i would like to do without button. some help?

```
app.post('/windproducts', async (req, res) =>{    
let tipoProducto = req.body.tipo_producto;
console.log(tipoProducto)

const windproducts = await WindProduct.find({"tipo_producto": {$eq:tipoProducto}})

res.redirect('windproducts/tablas', {windproducts})
```

}
)

in EJS:

```
<form action="/windproducts" method="POST">
    <select id="productosTipo" class="validated-form" name="tipo_producto">        
    <option name="" value="">Todo</option>
    <option name="tabla" value="tabla">Tabla</option>
    <option name="vela" value="vela">Vela</option>       
  </select>
  <!-- <button class="btn btn-success">mostrar</button> -->
</form>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`<% %>`
use this syntax in your view file to use foreach loop on object

```
<%
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
%>
  // HTML Code
<%
});
%>
```

Comment: i have this syntax after the form. But the <% %> not will return the objects if first the req.body, post the value in express to find().